# Force ContentPanel to relayout its components

Tags: gwt, gxt

I implemented a Horizontal splittable panel with a BorderLayoutContainer and 2 ContentPanel:

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  ContentPanel 1           |  ContentPanel2     |
|                           |                    |
| component 1 - component 2 |                    |
|                         <-|->                  |
|                           |                    |
|                           |                    |
--------------------------------------------------
```

With this code :

```
public class WestCenter extends BorderLayoutContainer {

  private ContentPanel westPanel;
  private ContentPanel centerPanel;

  public WestCenter(){
    westPanel = new ContentPanel();
    centerPanel = new ContentPanel();

    BorderLayoutData westData=new BorderLayoutData(800);
    westData.setSplit(true);
    westData.setCollapsible(true);
    westData.setMinSize(300);
    westData.setMaxSize(2000);
    westData.setMargins(new Margins(0,5,0,0));

    BorderLayoutData centerData=new BorderLayoutData();
    setWestWidget(westPanel, westData);
    setCenterWidget(centerPanel,centerData);
  }
  ...
  //Getters, Setters etc...
```

}

**Problem :**

When the user drags the bar so that "component 1" and "component 2" cannot fit in the same line anymore, there is some problems in the height calculation, resulting in a bad display.

```
--------------------------------------------------
|  ContentPanel 1  |        ContentPanel2        |
|                  |                             |
| component 1      |                             |
| component 2    <-|->                           |
|                  |                             |
| *bad display for |                             |
| compos here*     |                             |
--------------------------------------------------
```

**But**

If I manually redrag by 1px, the display is good again (even with "component 1" and "component 2" on 2 lines).

**Question**

How can I force the ContentPanel to redisplay its content?

Up to now, the only way I found is (very) ugly: add a resize handler on the contentPanel to set the width to width-1.

The problem is that this handler generates another resize event, resulting in an infinite loop. But with the help of a Timer, I validated that the display problem was solved by this change of width :

```
westPanel.addResizeHandler(new ResizeHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onResize(final ResizeEvent event) {
    Timer t=new Timer(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
        westPanel.setWidth(westPanel.getOffsetWidth()-1);
      }
    };
    t.schedule(2000);
  }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: why you didn't used viewport??may be it will help you.

Comment: I dit not know the existence of this class so I read the documentation about it. The doc explains that you have to create one ViewPort and add it to the RootPanel. The problem is that I use GWTP and revealPlace() methods so I never directly access to the RootPanel(). Do you know how to mix GXT ViewPort with GWTP?

Comment: ContentPanel.layout(true)?